# Rails 3.2 Query Format Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, optimization

Okay, at the moment I have the following in my model:

```
has_many :current_monitorings, :class_name => "Monitoring",
:conditions => proc { [ 'monitorings.created_at > ?', Time.now.midnight ] }
```

I want to add a condition to this that checks if the outlet is_active attribute is set to false. I tried doing it like this:

```
has_many :current_monitorings, :class_name => "Monitoring",
:conditions => proc { [ 'monitorings.created_at > ? AND outlet.is_active = ?', Time.now.midnight, 'false' ] }
```

However, this doesn't work. I'm probably being stupid, but any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sql, `outlet.is_active` should be `outlets.is_active`. Assuming is_active is a boolean field, just pass `false` and not `"false"`:

Try this:

```
has_many :monitorings

def current_monitorings
  monitorings.joins(:outlets).where(
    'monitorings.created_at > ? AND outlets.is_active = ?',
    Time.now.midnight,
    false
  )
end
```

Comment: This leaves me with `PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "outlets"`

Comment: It shouldn't. It only performs 1 query.

Comment: How would I call this from a different model. I'm trying to call this on the user model. However, I need to use this in my dashboard_controller.rb